# The most efficient way to calculate nCr mod M in cases when M isn't prime

Tags: algorithm, modulo, ncr, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have always faced lots of questions on online coding platforms dealing with `nCr mod M` where M is usually a prime. In the cases where it is not, we usually prefer to use the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Could we do this more easily than the Chinese Remainder Theorem, i.e. by writing less code if we simply have to calculate N mod M where M is not prime?

Comment: What language are you using? Can you use modulus operator?

Comment: @JacobSeleznev:I am using C/C++

Comment: Do you want to determine a number n that when divided by some given divisors leaves given remainders? Or you want to find the remainder of division of one number by another([Modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operation)

Comment: @KavishDwivedi you have to give more info about the field (in a algebraic sense) you are working on. For instance, why `int v = n % m` is not enough.

Comment: @KavishDwivedi, your problem, which I understand is talking about [this](http://comeoncodeon.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/combination/), is probably more appropriate for [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com).